# server side of adsense

Tags: php, javascript, client-server

Google ask you to add a javascript code to your page and it will generate the links. The script has some id which are sent to the server, but I don't know how.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1234567890123456";
/* snipet_name */
google_ad_slot = "123456789";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

I'm curious to know how the client and slot ids are send to the server. Javascript is client side and I wish to know how those parameters are sent to the server in order to query a db and to return the links.

A link, sample, explanation related to PHP will work great for me.
TY

Comment: The answer is simple: **AJAX.** As for explanation related to PHP, there is nothing special to explain. PHP acts just usual way.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I don't think so. I don't see anything in `show_ads.js` using `XMLHttpRequest`, which would be the usual definition of "ajax".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that javascript is client side. However, it does have abilities to communicate with a server. I'm unable to access the source referenced in this question (it's showing up as a blank screen), I'm forced to work with the answers above and my own knowledge of javascript.

First, Google ads are not hosted only on Google domain sites. That removes ANY possibility of using AJAX without a PHP proxy located within the domain being used. As I never remembered using such a proxy when I set up Adsense, I can safely assume that the cross domain limitations (you can read about the same source origin policy [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) will apply (i.e. a javascript file from somedomain.com cannot communication to anotherdomain.com, unless using a workaround), and the .js file does not contain any references to `XMLHttpRequest`. However, there are ways to work around this, not just using the PHP proxy that I noted above.

Cross domain workarounds:

1. Using a tracking pixel. I noticed that someone above said a image tag was seen in the source. What the code does is generate a link to an image file (say `www.googleAdTracker.com/trackingPixel.gif?userid=XXX&site=yourSite`) and the parameters within the URL will be used to identify the user, the site, and all the other parameters Google Adsense needs to work. Alternatively, it can capture the user's IP address (as this is submitted with any transaction within HTTP (that I can remember)), as well as set cookies that enable Adsense to not just track the website, but the users. In Firefox, to go Tools->Options->Privacy->remove individual cookies, and you can view, search, and possible edit (if you install a certain plugin, I believe) the individual cookies. That's how Google has become a target of privacy groups, their ads and their cookies are spread all over the net, and they can track everything I'm doing, the general type of sites I go to, what I'm interested in. This is not just so Google can handle over info to the U.S. government (yes, it does do that, just search it up on any credible news site) when asked, but also to see what I'm interested in, and thus serve up applicable ads to me.
2. A second workaround is via the setting of an iframe. You create a new iframe object `frame=document.createElement("iframe")`, and then set the `src` value of the iframe to a URL, and that will enable them to send a one way communication to the server (well, the server can reply, but it'll be in the iframe, which will not be accessible from the Javascript code in the page). Like above, the parameters in the request URL, and the cookies/content of the iframe will enable tracking of users and sites.
3. Last week, I found this interesting site that claims to have found a way using jQuery to work around the cross domain restrictions, you can read about it [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/), but I'm  certain Google Adsense does not use it
4. I've also heard of workarounds using adobe Flash, but the problem is that not all users have flash installed

Back to your question regarding the requests. Simplest way I can think of (without decompiling pages of javascript code) is to install [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) into Firefox (if you don't have Firefox, install it). I suggest [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) as well, not just for this project, as it is very useful. After you install Live HTTP Headers, and restarted Firefox, go to Tools->Live HTTP Headers, and then go to the site in question, the one with the ads. Then, you can go to the LHH window, and you can see exactly what requests are being made, and all the behind-the-scene communications your browser makes, and all the parameters being passed to the Google Adsense servers. (Like I said above, I haven't seen the source of the .js file in question, so most of what I said above is from experience and intuitive guessing).

Now, you've also mentioned above using PHP. Well, when Javascript communications with PHP, say load up a page: `yoursite.com/test.php?foo=bar&testing=123`, the PHP file receives the arguments in a variable, stored in an array in `$_REQUEST` (and other variables hold the same info, but that's not my point). For example, the test.php file in the example link above has the `$_REQUEST` array containing two interesting keys and values. `$_REQUEST['foo']` is set to `bar` and `$_REQUEST['testing']` is set to `123`. So, the receiving PHP file can use this, and if the user_id, or `google_ad_client` was in the URL, it would be in that array, and the PHP file can process the request. It can also access the cookies (cookies data is sent with the request), and also track you down that way. Moreover, the client's IP address is stored in the PHP variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. All this info is probably used in processing and logged in a database (probably MySQL or something similar), and stored on Google servers.

Using this knowledge, you can fake the adsense requests, as in sending the request that you got from Live HTTP Headers via a proxy to the destination (be careful, as cookies data is hard to replicate and still seem authentic, and also the fact that a timestamp may be included within the request, sometimes in encrypted form). It's definitely against the Terms of Service, but I'm only giving you knowledge, it's your choice on what you want to use it on.

On another slightly related subject, to send requests manually, you can send GET requests manually on your browser, and use javascript or PHP to send POST requests. If you're using PHP, look into cURL. Below is an example of sending a POST requests to a site (in this case, it's my old code to log in to a Facebook account using an email and password, can be adapted to basically any request to any site:

```
$postData = "charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&lsd=" . $lsd . "&locale=en_US&email=" . $login[$i][0] . "&pass=" . $login[$i][5] . "&persistent=1&default_persistent=1&charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&lsd=" . $lsd;
$postDataLength = "Content-Length: " . strlen($postData);
$login = curl_init("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "FBcookies.txt"); 
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "FBcookies.txt"); 
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate"); 
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com/"); 
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', $postDataLength ));  
$response = curl_exec($login);
curl_close($login);
```

Read more about CURL [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).
[Link to contact me](http://shadowx360.heliohost.org/contact.html) if you want to notify me if anything above is unclear and I need to elaborate more.

As a final note, here's my Disclaimer: "I have NEVER tried to send fake adsense headers, and I'm not encouraging you to do so. I am also not responsible for any physical injury, death, or maiming that may happen to you, your possessions, your computer, your Google account, your general well being, or your happiness that occurs from the use of the above knowledge." I think I've safely covered my own behind with that statement. Any more questions, just let me know using that contact link above.

Comment: 1) Many thx LostInTheCode for your valuable replay.   
2) I have no intention to hack adsense or anything bad to anyone(google, users) etc, but ur disclamer is really funny. Thx for that too :) Wishing you a perfect day!

Comment: +1 For a well written and informative answer that's useful for more than just Google!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the first few lines are setting up variables that the code in `show_ads.js` is using; it's the bit in `show_ads.js` that actually sends the information to the Google server. You have to dive into the minified source of `show_ads.js` to see how, but I believe it uses that information to construct an `iframe` href and/or `img` src. It may well do other things based on the capabilities of the browser your user is using. If you really want to know, you can pick apart the source, but you can definitely see it using this for an `img` src in at least one place (search on "ad_client").

But in general, because they've set up those global variables, they can access them from `show_ads.js` and do anything with that that's possible with JavaScript.

---

Be aware that attempting to reverse-engineer AdSense may well violate the T&Cs. And Google is fairly draconian (and *completely* opaque) about closing accounts if they sense a violation.

Comment: javascript is client side and I don't see how to send any variable to a server side application.

Comment: @dole: As I said, one of the things that `show_ads.js` (which runs *client-side*) does is use the variable `google_ad_client` in constructing a `src` attribute for an `img`. It uses it as part of the query string on the image `src` URL. Then it adds that image to the DOM, triggering the browser to retrieve the image. The browser does that using the URL, which includes the query string parameters -- including the `google_ad_client` value. So that's how it goes from client to server. It may also do the same with the `href` of an `iframe`, or anything else that involves a URL that gets fetched.