# javascript cumulative CPU usage

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax application which is taking an additional cpu usage of roughly 1% each time an ajax transaction is performed.

If there's no user activity after 1 hours then the page reloads and cpu usage drops down to less than 5%, but with each ajax transaction performed, the cpu usage increases and will never be released until a page reload.

I suspected orphan timers, but I can't seem to find any, I am using firefox and firebug and profiling shows the calls I would expect. If I profile after the transaction has completed and the page is inactive (other than a 1 second timer clock) I don't see any timers running other than the real time on screen clock.

Any suggestions on what this may be and how I can track it down ??

I am using pure javascript.

Comment: Someone had the same discussion regarding a seemingly simple BBC counting script here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4534459/538866
Can this aid you?

Comment: It's not the AJAX, it's something you are doing with the response each time. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved it, my initial instinct was correct, every time the ajax calls, it syncs the server time with the local real time clock, as it is crucial that they are synced.

I had not assigned a variable to the setInterval() function and not cleared the old setInterval() with window.clearInterval() before re-syncing the local clock. This resulted in ever increasing setInterval() active calls.

Thanks anyway :-)